# Retrieving a large amount of data through curl and php

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, curl

I have a project where we have an internal mssql warehouse not available over the internet. The user needs to be able to run a query from a normal website which can query this internal warehouse and receive a report.

To do this, I have created a script on an internal server (is available over the internet) which runs the queries on the mssql server (via the intranet) and returns a string of data (using php://output)

In order to get this working on the website side, I have created a php file on the remote server which does a curl request to the internal server (with variables i've passed in), when the curl request finishes it passes the variable back in to the website which writes the contents to a file, then in turn I redirect the user to this file.

This works perfectly with a few caveats...

If the query that is being run is big (they can be absolutely massive) its possible the server can take a long time (over 3/4 hours) to run the queries (indexing on the internal warehouse is not handled by me). Although the curl request continues to run, I do find sometimes it fails.

I have 2 options for the user, 1 is to wait for the request to finish, so an ajax request then goes off to do all this and when it is done they are redirected to the file.... this sometimes never returns... so the user is left waiting for it come back forever - i have tried to get around this by checking for the file on the file system every 5 seconds and if found then download it - this has worked to some extent... but again sometimes it still does fail.

The second option is to email the report once finished allowing the user to leave the website and let it continue to do the curl request in the background, however again if the query takes a LONG time to run, I seem to get empty emails as if the curl request has timed out.

I'm a bit lost on why it fails if the query takes a long time or why the javascript sometimes fails to report that it is complete. Any information to point me in the right direction would be useful - I dont think i'm far off having this working perfectly.

The warehouse has over 100 Million records.

Comment: whats your RDM: mysql or sql-server?

Comment: this is pretty much all sql-server although the website runs on mysql, this request doesn't touch mysql at all.

Comment: Can you post the cURL code you are using?

Comment: Dont have the code handy atm, it is the standard curl code which timeout set to infinite. I have found out now though that the curl is not failing, it does always create the report which is good, its more the user interface side which sometimes just hangs, Before I had on jquery fail then it would simply end the request, this was a bad idea as it was still generating the report and although the jquery was throwing an error, if i ignore the error and let it continue it does finish.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're trying to solve an OLAP issue with a OLTP toolset.

Given you're situation and issues with CURL timing out (HTTP usually isn't the best thing for long running report generation like this), my suggestion would be to scrap the synchronous route for an asynchronous one where the client submits a report, receives back a token and the client checks in every so often to see if the job relating to the token has completed.

You could even get fancy and give the client status updates when they check in and it's not done, or tie it into your email idea (depending on the size of the rendered report) and dispatch an email.  The key is to not rely on a brittle curl connection, and rather rely on local processes (via crontab or the pthread library).

Comment: This is what I want to do in the long term so bascially I'll store a token in the database and the user can come back whenever to see it complete - but is no good for short term. I might have solved it anyways, I think jquery was throwing an error but not one that actually stops the ajax running strangely enough, if on error i just let it continue it seems to still generate the report and work as expected